# Can I Use Minor Illusion to create a 5ft box around myself to block a scrying sensor's sight?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion, divination

My party is being scryed on by an enemy. We are all low level and don't have access to second level spells yet.

I want to use paper and quill, to write down sensitive information, then pass the folded up paper to a party member to read it. I want to cast minor illusion around myself as a 5ft cube of hollow stone while writing and around the recipient while reading. My theory is that because the scrying sensor is always 10ft away from the target they would just see a block of stone.

**Does this work?**

From Scrying:

> On a failed save, the spell creates an invisible sensor within **10 feet** of the target. You can see and hear through the sensor as if you were there. The sensor moves with the target, **remaining within 10 feet** of it for the duration.

Comment: Try to pass false information through the scrying sensor? Do the illusion, pass the message, but have the message be false. Use Detect Magic to find a time that the scrying sensor is inactive (everyone sleeps sometime). Share the plan, and then, make it so that the bad guys can get the information, but its fake. (For an example of this in action, see the movie Rainmaker with Matt Damon).

Answer (score 14):

### This might disrupt the opponent a little, but won't completely keep you safe.

Firstly, I read the wording of Scrying a little differently to you. In my opinion, "within 10 feet" means "no more than 10 feet away, and potentially closer," rather than the "exactly 10 feet away" you're interpreting it as. There's no indication that the caster can voluntarily move the sensor, but my interpretation as a GM would be that if cast targeting an individual, it appears *no more than* 10 feet away, but will automatically move to a position that gives an unobstructed view of the target (if one exists).

Your GM might rule that differently to the way I would, but there's another problem. If this strategy works, it's much more likely to work for actions you can do very quickly than for writing a long, detailed explanation.

According to the text for [Minor Illusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/minor-illusion),

> If a creature uses its action to examine the sound or image, the creature can determine that it is an illusion with a successful Intelligence (Investigation) check against your spell save DC. If a creature discerns the illusion for what it is, the illusion becomes faint to the creature.

The enemy scrying you will know the illusion is likely to be an illusion, as they see it come into being; they likely know to examine it to see if they can pierce it; and it'll probably only take a few rounds for their Investigation roll to beat your spell save DC. Once they do, it will become faint to them and they'll be able to see through it to what you're doing inside. Once they've cottoned onto the trick, they may start readying actions to examine your illusions the moment they come into being; you'll only have a brief window, if any time at all, in which they can't see you.